# Need to place multiple orders for stocks

Tags: python, slice

I need to code in python for placing orders for stocks. Each order cannot exceed a certain quantity, say 600. If the required quantity is 1900, I would need to place three orders, 3 of 600 each and 1 of the remaining. I tried a for loop:

```
max_qty=600
req_qty=1900
for qty in range(max_qty, req_qty, max_qty):
   print(qty)
```

This does not seem to be the right method. Pls help.

Comment: Are you unable to figure out the algorithm? Could you write out in English what you are trying to do?

Comment: No need for an algorithm: try `divmod(1900,600)`

Comment: Your code right now prints 600, 1200 and then 1800. What would you like to do? Print 600 three times and then 100 one time?

Comment: @blackbrandt - I am learning code in python. Here I am intending to place orders for stocks. Each order is restricted (max quantity) to 600 units. If I  need to place an order for more than the max permitted quantity, then I would have to order in multiples of 600 or less, until  the required quantity is reached. I would write a function to place an order for the max quantity and execute it a number of times in loop until the required quantity is ordered.

Comment: @ Skapis9999 - yes, you are right. If the required quantity is only 300, then order once with 300 as quantity. If the required quantity is 900, then order once with 600 as quantity and then again for the remaining 300. So place the function for ordering, in a loop until the required quantity is ordered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following, where I have put in a function `place_order` to represent what ever the code for placing the actual order is.

1. Loop while we still have a remaining number of stocks to order
2. Get a quantity for the next sub-order which is the *smaller* of the requested quantity or the max limit
3. Place the order for the largest possible amount at once.
4. Update the outstanding requested amount by subtracting the ordered amount

```
def place_order(qty):
    # Do the actual ordering
    ...
    

max_qty=600
req_qty=1900

while req_qty:
    order_qty = min(req_qty, max_qty)
    place_order(order_qty)   # Place the order
    req_qty -= order_qty
```

Some things I didn't include as they are beyond the scope of the original question:

1. You could have place_order return a True or False of whether it was actually successful and only update req_qty on success
2. In an actual application you might use something like async/await on the ordering function so that you can place multiple orders without waiting for the previous order to complete.

Comment: thanks for your suggestions. It does appear right. Just wondering if a range or slicing method could be used here....

Comment: Range and slicing don't really fit here, because you're going to keep getting values > max_qty.  It could be done, but it wouldn't make a lot of sense.  Something like  `for qty in range(req_qty, 0, -max_qty):`  `order_qty = max_qty if qty > max_qty else qty`

Answer (score 1):

Here is a piece of code making use of `divmod`:

```
max_qty=600
req_qty=1900
full_orders, remainder = divmod(req_qty, max_qty)
for i in range(full_orders):
    place_order(max_qty)
if remainder:
    place_order(remainder)
```